# Cache System and Cookie reading Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, cache, cookie

In the `header.phtml` I have a **DIV** which gets visible only when a **cookie** is NOT set in the browser.

```
<?php if (Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->get('cookiex') == '') { ?>
    <div></div>
<?php } ?>
```

Sometimes when I refresh the page **(ctrl+R)** or when I refresh the **Block Cache in admin**, the DIV becomes **visible** ALTHOUGH the **cookie** is still **present** in the browser.

If there is a mistake in my approach , I am not able to identify it.

Can you give me some idea , please ?